# is it impossible to use two @ModelAttribute in one controller?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have a page jsp where i will use many attribute from different Classes so I need to use two @ModelAttribute in my controller. also if i use two @ModelAttribute in one controller i must put two commandName in my Form . is that possible ?

**This is my form : (Fonction is an attribute in the class Activite and Name of Etablissement is an attribute in the Class Etablissement :**

```
                    <table id="tabmenu">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fonction :</td>
                            <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="fonction" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nom d'établissement :</td>
                            <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="noml"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ville :</td>
                            <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="villel"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Délégation :</td>
                            <td><form:input type="text" class="round default-width-input" path="cd_reg" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date début :</td>
                            <td><form:input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="" path="dateAffect"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Date fin :</td>
                            <td><form:input type="text" name="date" class="tcal" value="" path="dateAffect"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input
                                class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"
                                type="submit" value="Créer" /></td>
                            <td><input
                                class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow"
                                type="reset" value="Initialiser" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    </form:form>
```

The controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/fiche_service",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView Fiche_service(@ModelAttribute Activite activite,@ModelAttribute Etablissement etabl,ModelMap model) {
    Agent ag = new Agent();
    return new ModelAndView("FicheService","agent",ag);

}
```

**Activite POJO :**

```
public class Activite {

    int code_act;
    String cd_modaff;
    String cd_etab;
    String fonction;
    int ppr;
    String CINA;
    String CINN;

    public Activite() {
        super();
    }
    //getters and setters ....

}
```

**Etablissement POJO**

```
public class Etablissement {

    String code_etab;
    String code_gipe;
    String noml;
    String noma;
    String cd_orgTutel;
    String cd_reg;
    String cd_prov;
    String cd_com;
    String cd_mil;
    String cd_cauto;
    String adressel;
    String cp;
    String villel;

  //getters and sitters 
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you try it first.

Comment: i try it it's  not working so I really need a solution, because i can't use just one class in each page i need manay object class at once and it's impossible to provide them by @ModelAttribute.

Comment: You can put any number of `@ModelAttribute` but you I doubt you can have many `commandName` in the form tag. There are workarounds. Show us some code.

Comment: Yes exacltly the problem is with commandName,See the code above.

Comment: You would have to use normal `html <form>` and use the full model attribute description, such as `${agent.property}`

Comment: You mean use the simple form and in the controller i just add attributes like that : **model.addAttributes** ?

Comment: No, your controller seems fine. I mean for your View, the jsp should just have `<form>` instead of spring's `<form:input>` and other form tag elements.

Comment: that will not work, the form must know with each object will work

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. The form only know something from the Spring/JSP perspective. It ends up generating html (which you can look at in your browser). Instead of letting Spring do it, you do it directly.

Comment: but without using form tags of spring i could not use path nor connect the form with my Dao methods. Have you an example of that?

Comment: Show me your model beans, like what does `Agent` look like?

Comment: Agent is an object i used for showing data from database in the same page. the problem now is i want to insert other data in this page and those data belongs to differents classes ( Activite and Etablissement) I will provide them now in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can have only one command object per form. If you have multiple forms, then only you can have multiple command objects. Do you need multiple command  objects for same form? If you do, I would suggest combine the required properties in a single class, since they belong to the same form.

Comment: I thought in this solution, but i have to respect my conception! i can't add a class that i don't have in my digram of classes